# Installing SIP for Python 2.7 on Mac

Tags: python, ros, python-sip

I am currently installing ROS Melodic on my Mac and the installation requires to have python SIP library. Here is where the problem comes; when I try to `pip install sip` in my terminal I get the following response:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sip (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for sip
```

Whereas if I try to install it on python 3 with `pip3 install sip` I have no problems. The ROS installation has to be done on python 2.7.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: You could try installing [an older version](https://pypi.org/project/sip/#history). 5.0.0 seems to be the first one that explicitly requires Python 3, so you could try `pip install sip<5`. Note that Python 2 went end of life on the 1st of January 2020, so you should think carefully about whether you want to use software that only supports Python 2.